# invalid operands to binary expression ('char' and 'const std::basic_string<char>')

Tags: c++

I have a string which contains **`** char and I want to replace it with escaped form of same char.

```
// Turns ` to \' 
std::replace(script.begin(), script.end(), std::string("\\`"), std::string("\\\\`"));
```

However, the code won't compile,

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('char' and 'const std::basic_string<char>')
        if (*__first == __old_value)
            ~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::replace<std::__wrap_iter<char *>, std::basic_string<char>>' requested here
            std::replace(script.begin(), script.end(), std::string("\\`"), std::string("\\\\`"));
```

Comment: std::replace replaces a single element of a sequence with a single element, not arbitrary subsequences. You probably want std::regex_replace.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. This replace single element. You didn't read my question and closed it. WTF!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I posted this question to solve the types issue!!!

Comment: I didn't close it, someone else did. Make sure you read all the answers to the duplicate question.